# Transforming publishing settings to reporting settings of the Report Generator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, report, settings, publish

I have a Matlab code that publishes some descriptions, the plot and results in a pdf file but I want the published pdf's name to be incremented (like myReport1, myReport2 , ...) and possibly configuring the image quality of the figures and adding time stamps. The Report Generator on the other hand seems to require manual selection of the bits and pieces of the report from scratch.

So I would like to know if there is a way to transform my publishing settings into reporting settings of the Report Generator so that what I'm publishing now could be seen as a report and adding the things I want to that report setup file.

If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

In general the reporting part of the code looks like this:

```
  %% Resutls
    % This is section is reports the results.  

    %%
    % 
    % The data collected from the mobile human behaviour recording 
    % application
    % 

    logData
```

where logData is a matrix.

I tried the Report Generator but when I report a pdf, it writes the titles and other things that the Report Generator was supposed to generate (not my own texts) as dashes but when I report in html format, it's fine. Does anybody know why?

Comment: All of what you mention should be possible. Without **any** knowledge of your code, the *Report Generator*, it is **impossible** to help you. Could you ask a defined question, that can be answered?

Comment: I'm not sure if the code helps because I have to explain the things I have done but the code doesn't have much to do with the report generation but I will edit my question.

Comment: It would be very useful if the Report Generator could Import a MATLAB (.m) file and produce a .rpt file that could then be edited to customize the report. However, it does not appear as if such a capability exists. It appears as if it would require significant effort to perform this operation manually.